# Check that a string exists within another string with regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex

I've got a regular expression that I am using to strip an extension from another string

The extensions in this example are

```
BK|BZ|113
```

If the string does not contain any of the extensions, then I need it to leave the string as is.

The regular expression I'm using is

```
base_value = base_string[/(.*?[^-])-?(?:BK|BZ|113)/,1]
```

However, if the base_value does not contain the string, I want to return the base_value. I thought I could use

```
base_value = base_string
base_value = base_string[/(.*?[^-])-?(?:BK|BZ|113)/,1] unless (base_value !~ /(.*?[^-])-?(?:BK|BZ|113)) == false
```

but that isn't working.

What is the best way to return the base_string if the extensions are not found?

Comment: Can you give some example inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well, you want to strip the regexp from a string, if it matches, right? So.. do it:

```
string.sub(/(?:BK|BZ|113)$/, "")
```

Comment: Your approach is the better than mine, I guess I got stuck on what he had written, up!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use sub like this:

```
base_string1 = "test1BK"
base_string2 = "test2"

p base_string1.sub(/(.*?[^-])-?(?:BK|BZ|113)/,'\1')
p base_string2.sub(/(.*?[^-])-?(?:BK|BZ|113)/,'\1')
```

When the pattern is not found nothing is replaced, otherwise it returns the string without the extension.

Answer (score 0):

If `/(.*?[^-])-?(?:BK|BZ|113)/` doesn't match then `base_string[/(.*?[^-])-?(?:BK|BZ|113)/,1]` will be `nil`. So this should work:

```
base_value = base_string[/(.*?[^-])-?(?:BK|BZ|113)/,1] || base_string
```